# How do I specify a zone whitelist constraint for a state in Corda?

Tags: corda

In Corda, when I add an output state to a `TransactionBuilder`, it defaults to using a hash constraint.

If I want to use a zone whitelist constraint instead, do I need to add the output state to the `TransactionBuilder` as follows?

```
txBuilder.addOutputState(
    state,
    State.CONTRACT_ID, 
    WhitelistedByZoneAttachmentConstraint.INSTANCE)
```

If so, does this mean that I need to change all my flows to specify a zone whitelist constraint in this way? Or is there a way to trigger the use of zone whitelist constraints automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The node will automatically substitute a hash constraint for a zone whitelist constraint if the contract in question has been whitelisted with the zone operator.

If you set a zone whitelist constraint manually, but the contract in question hasn't been whitelisted with the zone operator, the transaction will fail verification.